# printf("%f", aa) when aa is of type int

Tags: c, printf

```
double a = 3.1456;

int aa=2.0;      

printf ("%f \n",a );    
printf("%f \n",aa);
```

The answer is `3.145600  ,3.145599.`
I have tried different values of a, and the outputs aa seem to have some relationship with a.
I am confused. What's the reason?
~
~
~
~

Comment: `aa` is int type so requires %d format

Comment: Which book are you reading? *Hint: A book would have solved this problem for you. Don't learn C by misguided trial and error!*

Comment: I don't think that answer is helpful. I am wondering why a is 3.145600 and aa is not exactly the same with a. aa is 3.144599 .

Comment: Check on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php, you'll find your answer.

Comment: `if type is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument 
(as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undeﬁned`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ingo Leonhardt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17943575/134633) is correct to say that your program's behaviour is undefined - the output isn't going to be consistent under optimisation or on different architectures / compilers.

However, the specific reason that you're seeing 3.1456 mutated to 3.145599 in this case is explicable.  It can be inferred that your architecture uses IEEE-754 8-byte `double`s and 4-byte little-endian `int`s.  The hexadecimal representation of the nearest 8-byte double to 3.1456 is:

```
0x40092a305532617c
```

where the sign is `0`, the exponent field is `0x400` (representing an exponent of 1) and the mantissa field is `0x92a305532617c` (representing a hexadecimal mantissa of 0x1.92a305532617c).  If you overwrite the lower 4 bytes of this with the 4-byte integer 2, then you get:

```
0x40092a3000000002
```

This has the sign and exponent unchanged, but the mantissa has changed to 0x1.92a3000000002, or 0x0.000005532617a less than the original.  With an exponent of 1, this represents a difference of 0x0.00000aa64c2f4, which in decimal is ~0.000000634766.  When you subtract this from 3.1456 you get ~3.145599365234, which rounds to 3.145599.

Comment: thanks,that's helpful

Answer (score 2):

`printf( "%f", ... )` expects a `double` as argument, but yu pass an integer. That's UB. As In your case, as `sizeof(double) > sizeof(int)`, the second printf() probably reads some bytes from the stack that are 'still there' from the previous call. If you added some other function alls between both, result woud be something else. But as it is UB it's *not defined* to be so, anything my happen

Comment: Or it may not read from the stack at all, but from a (floating point) register. I agree it is UB, but C standard certainly doesn't explain where from or how arguments are fetched inside printf.

Comment: @mats of course not, thaky for your comment. I've clearified that the stack thing is just a guess to explain why you still the sth. related to the double value